# When a Lysosome's bonding sites all get bonded to, what is the most resource and energy efficient way to handle the used Lysosome?

Tags: biochemistry, thermodynamics

Let's say a Lysosome that bonds to a hazardous material to neutralize it has all bonding sites used up. would it be more safe / efficient to excrete the entire Lysosome / hazardous material molecule or to bring it to a certain organelle / organ to unbind the material and send it for excretion and then have the Lysosome available for use again? In which way do Lysosomes in nature commonly handle this problem?

Comment: Enzymes are catalysts, i.e. by definition they don't get used up. More info on "cellular garbage disposal" can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysosome

Comment: Are you sure that you are referring to enzymes? Sounds more like you are talking about things like hemoglobin (not an enzyme), which binds to the waste product CO2 and carries it to the lungs for excretion.

Comment: okay yeah, see, I learned something I didn't even  realize I was going to. updating question to fit Lysosomes. Does it make more sense now what I was asking?